# TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I try to run the following code but receive an error. Anyone can help me to find the error. Thank you.

```
function hcSum(data) {

  var total=0;
  for (var i=0; i<data[0].length; i=i+2) {
    total = total + parseInt(data[0][i]);
  }

  return total;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Give an example input and expected output.

Comment: @aaron the error is specified in the title
@papacom that error tells you that (most likely) `data[0]` can't be resolved because `data` is undefined. Where are you calling your function `hcSum()` ?

Comment: Can you put the parameter value of the function?

Comment: I used hcSum() on Sheet1. I used =hcSum(A4:E4). It gives me the result but I don't know why the error still appear.

Comment: I still new to GAS. How to put the parameter value of the function?

Comment: Is that Excel? Edit your question to add that example and the relevant tag.

Comment: No. Google Sheet

Comment: @papacom - how are you calling your function `hcSum()`? Are you trying to create a [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Comment: @papacom how you are getting dat[0] ? explain your code in detail, the above code is of javascript or app script?